# Add paperclip new style doesn't affect old uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

I have Company model with logo image

```
has_attached_file :logo
```

I have created many companies with their logos.

Now, I need to add new style

```
has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :small => "30x15>", :medium => "155x85>" }
```

Should I re-upload all my old data to regenerate the new styles? I don't think so....
Or is there any rake task can regenerate styles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Thumbnail-Generation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation). If the rake task doesn't work for you, you should be able to use a snippet in the console to invoke reprocess! on the companies in question